# Merge array of arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to Merge two arrays in a array using JavaScript but I'm not getting the exact output using `concat` method. Can any one help me?

```
  var a1= [[0, 1],[1, 5],[2,5],[3,7]];
  var a2= [[1,9],[0,6],[3,8],[2,6]];
//output 
  var result=[[0,1,6],[1,5,9],[2,5,6],[3,7,8]];
```

for example **for every array in a1 find the corresponding (the elements at index zero match) array in a2 and merge the elements**

code which I have retied

```js
var v1 = [[0, 1],[1, 5],[2,5]];
var v2 = [[0,5],[1,6],[2,8]];
    
const res = v1.map((x, i) => [...new Set([...x, ...v2[i]])]);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: What is the expected output? Also, what didn't work with `concat()`?

Comment: can you explain your logic behind your output/result array?

Comment: @NickParsons Seems to be: _for every array in `a1` find the corresponding (the elements at index zero match) array in `a2` and merge the elements_

Comment: @Andreas ah, I see, thanks :). That seems correct

Comment: @Andreas you are correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we translate your requirement "literally" one solution could look like this:

```js
const a1 = [[0, 1], [1, 5], [2, 5], [3, 7]],
      a2 = [[1, 9], [0, 6], [3, 8], [2, 6]];

const result = a1.map(a1x => {
  // find the corresponding array
  const x2 = a2.find(a2x => a2x[0] === a1x[0]);

  // combine the values in a new array
  if (x2) {
    a1x = a1x.concat(x2);
  }

  // return an array of unique values
  return [...new Set(a1x)];
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Minimizing this into a one-liner is up to OP :)

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), collect all values grouped by the first element and return an array of arrays with key and values.

```js
var a1 = [[0, 1], [1, 5], [2, 5], [3, 7]],
    a2 = [[1, 9], [0, 6], [3, 8], [2, 6]],
    result = Array.from(
        [a1, a2].reduce(
            (m, a) => a.reduce((n, [k, v]) => n.set(k, [...(m.get(k) || []), v]), m),
            new Map
        ),
        ([k, v]) => [k, ...v]
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```